# Show that the minimum polynomials of similiar matrices are the same

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

If $A$ is similiar to $A'$ ie $A'=C^{-1}AC$ for some invertible matrix $C$, show that the minimum polynomials are the same, ie  $m_A(x)=m_{A'}(x)$.

Comment: not sure where to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show that conjugation of matrices $M\mapsto CMC^{-1}$ commutes with evaluation of a polynomial$~P$ at matrices $M\mapsto P[M]$. The rest is obvious, a matrix is zero if and only it its conjugate is.

Answer (score 0):

If you define the minimum polynomial for *linear transformations*, instead of just for matrices, then this is clear, because similar matrices correspond to the same transformation; similarity corresponds to change of basis.

In particular, $A$ and $A'$ define the *same* linear transformation on $\mathbb R^n$, just expressed in different bases.

Comment: sorry i see why this is, but not how you would use it. This is my problem.

Comment: @1234, see my edited answer.